A question about useEffect and multiple useState
I have this code that listens to changes in carts useContext and it is supposed to keep the component up to date with the changes in carts since it is coming from an API
    const [isInCart, setIsInCart] = useState({
        quantity: undefined
    })
    const [qtyCounter, setQtyCounter] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        const productInCart = cart.cartItems.map((item) => item).find((item) => item.productId === product._id)
        if (productInCart) setIsInCart({ quantity: productInCart.quantity });
        if (isInCart.quantity) setQtyCounter(isInCart.quantity)
        console.log("1st", productInCart);
        console.log("2nd", isInCart);
        console.log("3rd", qtyCounter);

    }, [cart]

And this is the output whenever I try to change the cart values
console logs
I know this is missing a lot of context about my code but I think these are the code relevant for my question
Once I observed the logs in the console I did fix it by removing the unnecessary variables (I also dont remember why I added those)
    useEffect(() => {
        const productInCart = cart.cartItems.map((item) => item).find((item) => item.productId === product._id)
        if (productInCart) setQtyCounter(productInCart.quantity);
        if (!productInCart) setQtyCounter(0)

    }, [cart])

But the question still lingers in my head why does the useEffect behave like thatt with multiple useState?

Please don't link a png to show us your log outputs; put relevant log output in your question's text body.

Thanks for the response! I am fairly new to posting in stackoverflow so I was actually expecting to have the image displayed along with my text not just link it.

In short, when you call setIsInCart the state update doesn't happen immediately - react batches state update for performance reasons. As you said those variables are not necessary, but if for any reason in the future you want to add some operation right after state change you can use another useEffect:
useEffect(() => {
  const productInCart = cart.cartItems.find(item => item.productId === product._id);
  if (productInCart) {
    setIsInCart({ quantity: productInCart.quantity });
  }
}, [cart]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (isInCart.quantity) {
    setQtyCounter(isInCart.quantity);
  }
}, [isInCart]);

